# Can't change attribute of input tag using Javascript

Tags: javascript, input

I have an `<input>` tag which I would like to change programmatically. The input don't have inner text, it save its values on aria attributes.

So, here is the `<input>`:

```
<input type="text" id="foo" aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuemax="10" autocomplete="off" role="spinbutton" aria-valuenow="1">
```

Consider that we save the tag to the following `bla` variable:

```
var bla = document.getElementById("foo");
```

Below is a list of commands I tried using. But none of them worked.

- `bla.value = 2;`
- `bla.value = "2";`
- `bla.setAttribute("aria-valuenow",2);`
- `bla.setAttribute("aria-valuenow","2");`

Any ideas why? The `id` of the element is unique, I checked it. 
I am working on somebody's else code. Could it be possible that other developers changed the behavior of the `<input>`?

Comment: `input.value = "2";` should work. Is it possible you have another element with an ID called `input` ?

Comment: @FTM change the id to something unique

Comment: The id I have put here was just an example. The real id is completely different and certainly unique.

Comment: @FTM I think you should post more data - more HTML, more Javascript - something's not right and it's not clear what.

Comment: There must be some code breaking before executing this code, otherwise `bla.value = "2";` and `bla.setAttribute("aria-valuenow","2");` should work for sure. You can debug on your browser and check if something is breaking or not.

Comment: try to make a `console.log(bla);` and share the result

Comment: @NadirLaskar, the result is already shown on the question. Even after trying those methods, the bla variable don't change and keeps with its initial values.

Comment: @DarshitChokshi, I am almost certain that this is the case. Do you have more details on how to do this specific debug? To try to find out if something is now allowing the method to finish?

Comment: @FTM, You can debug JavaScript by opening up 'Developers Tools' on your browser. Press F12 to open 'Developers Tools', Rest of the things you can get it from here - [Debugging JavaScript in Chorme](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out my other users, please use unique Id while naming the `id` of an element. Below is the solution to your problem using `setAttribue()`.

```js
var input = document.getElementById("input");
input.setAttribute("aria-valuenow",2); // To set attribute to input element
console.log(input.hasAttribute('aria-valuenow')) // To check if input has the mentioned attribute
console.log(input.getAttribute('aria-valuenow')); // To access the value of the attribute
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input" aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuemax="10" autocomplete="off" role="spinbutton" aria-valuenow="2">
```

Comment: The id isn't the problem. The id is unique. And the setAttribute function is not working in my case. That is why I posted this question.

Comment: `console.log()` your element before and after the `setAttribute()`. Check the result.

Comment: Checked, no changes.

Comment: Can you share the result with me?

Comment: The initial value was 1. After running the commands you recommended, the results were `true` for `hasAttribute` and `1` for `getAttribute`. So, it didn't change to 2 as I would like using the `setAttribute` method.

Comment: Small request, please share `console.log()` of your html element.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148376/discussion-between-hassan-imam-and-ftm).

Answer (score -2):

You can use,

```
document.getElementById("mytext").value = "My value";
```

Comment: This answer has nothing to do with the PO's question. You just copied it from another answer in SO.

Comment: As I have written in my question, I tried that and it didn't work.